# Error Handling C++ : Program never stops

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling

I am just starting out C++, so excuse me for my misunderstanding.

I am making a program in which the next consonant is added on to every consonant.

For example, if the input is joythen the result is jkoyz.

Because k comes after j so it is inserted after j, o is vowel so nothing is inserted after o and z is inserted after y because z comes after y in the alphabet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    string str = "joy";

    string constant = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzz";

     for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){

        if (constant.find(str[i]) != string::npos) {

            int index = constant.find(str[i]);

            char closestConstant = constant[index + 1];           
            char *closestConstantPointer = &closestConstant;

            str.insert(0, closestConstantPointer);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the `str.insert(0, closestConstant);` line. Any guidance?

Comment: You already asked this.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I have fixed the arguments as the insert function accepts an index and a character pointer as arguments. The issue is different. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert (2)

Comment: Stop messing around with `char` and `char*` and do everything with std::string.

Comment: You're inserting a consonant, which increases the length of `str`. When you loop around again, are you checking the newly inserted consonant, resulting in a never ending loop of added consonants?

Comment: What's wrong with that line? What bad behavior do you observe?

Comment: I recommend investing some time in familiarizing yourself with [the debugging software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that almost certainly came with your development environment. Stepping through this program with a debugger would have shown you the mistake in a fraction of the time it took you to ask this question and wait for answers. The debugger is probably the greatest software productivity tool you will ever encounter, and the sooner you get good at using it, the sooner you can reap the rewards.

Comment: The version of `string::insert()` that takes a char pointer is meant to be used for **null terminated C style strings**, not single characters. Use the first variant with 1 for the `count`. Also, you're inserting into index 0, and you have the problem with `i` pointing to the newly inserting consonant as shown in John Perry's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a consonant, then increment `i` only once, your cursor ends up on the new consonant, so you're always adding new consonants. Like this:

```
joy
jkoy
jkloy
jklmoy
```

and so forth.

The solution is to increment `i` whenever you add a consonant. Retain the increment inside the `for` loop; you just need to increment `i` again right after the `str.insert(...)` command.

Comment: That's only part of the problem.

Comment: @FeiXiang I see your point in the comment. Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't think to look past the problems with the loop itself.